# Existence of informationally complete POVM on infinite dimensional Hilbert space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, mathematical-physics

Do there exist informationally complete POVM (in [this sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIC-POVM#Definition)) on infinite dimensional separable Hilbert spaces?

It is known that these exist in finite dimensions (I believe they were used in the proof of the quantum de Finetti theorem). But I can't find anything on their existence in the infinite dimensional case. All the definitions can be pushed in a natural way to this case, so it seems like a natural question.

Edit (details on informational completeness in infinite dimensional case): A POVM in the infinite dimensional case is a measure, i.e. a function from a measurable space $(X, \mathcal{M})$ (usually $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R})$) to the positive operators on $\mathcal{H}$. Then for a POVM $\mu$ to informationally complete, we want that the closed span of the image of $\mu$ under all sets in $\mathcal{M}$ to be the space of all (bounded) observables, where the closure is taken in the weak operator topology. Since then, if $O$ is a bounded operator, then there exists $c_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $E_n \in \mathcal{M}$ s.t.
$$O = \sum_n c_n \mu(E_n),$$
and so
$$\langle \psi | O| \psi \rangle  = \sum_n c_n \langle \psi | \mu(E_n)| \psi \rangle.$$
Hence we can compute the expectation of any observable.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen infinite-dimensional POVMs used, but one approach that might be fruitful for this is seeing POVMs as special kinds of *frames* of operators. The general theory of frames is developed for generic Hilbert spaces (a good reference is https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-8176-8224-8). An informationally complete POVM is a frame of bounded operators with some normalisation, see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0604049, sec III onwards.  I don't think there's anything specific that prevents you from doing this for POVMs on infinite-dimensional spaces

Comment: I would note though that you don't necessarily need a continuum of outcomes for the POVM (i.e. defining the POVM with a measure like you write). You could very well also find a IC-POVM with countably many outcomes I think